# How to use hooks with cucumber CLI?

Tags: java, cucumber, command-line-interface, hook

Iam using cucumber CLI and need use the hooks @Before, @After, @BeforeClass, @AfterClass. I declare the hooks in a class of my project, but cucumber ignores them when I run with CLI

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   

        args2 = new String[] { path + "/features", "--glue", "stepFiles",
                "--threads", threadsQty, "", "--tags", tags};

        cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(args2,Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());


    }

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario() {
        System.out.println("This will run before the Scenario");
    }

    @After
    public void afterScenario() {
        System.out.println("This will run after the Scenario");
    }
}
```

Comment: the hook class must be added as glue. try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hook class must be added as glue. try

```
args2 = new String[] { path + "/features", "--glue", "stepFiles", "--glue","<your hook class>",  "--threads", threadsQty, "", "--tags", tags};
```

Comment: you are right, i put the hooks class in the same directory with the step definitions, and it works